# (Ab) use Apache as a proxy

Tags: apache-httpd, proxy

I have a publicly available Apache server. Is it possible to redirect all incoming requests (e.g. http://publicname/test/) so that all accesses to /test/ are redirected to another server (in the private network, and not exposed to the internet, e.g. http://192.168.1.4/test/) without using anything besides Apache?

```
 Internet --- httpp://xx.xx.xx/> Public Apache <- 192. 168. 1 .3   --- 192.168.1 .4-> Private Apache
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this exact thing by modifying the apache configuration file, which is `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`.  All you have to do is add a section like this:

```
<Location /flask/>
    ProxyPass http://flask.intranet:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse http:/flask.intranet:8080/
</Location>
```

"intranet" is what I have set up as the internal domain name. "flask" is the internal-only  machine you have as 192.168.1.4.  I presume, but don't know for certain, that you could replace "flask.intranet" with "192.168.1.4".  The "/flask/" in the `<Location>` tag is what you refer to as "/test/".

I did this with Apache 2.2.21, but I bet it would work with other versions.  Also, don't do what I did, use `apachectl` to stop and start Apache before you try to troubleshoot a configuration that "isn't working".